# Calling from postman to EKS results in Access forbidden

Tags: postman, amazon-eks

I have a namespace called `opa` with `opa` running as server on `EKS`.
I see that the pod runs and looks ok.
I try to call it from `postman` and followed this [article](https://www.postman.com/postman/workspace/kubernetes-playground/documentation/13059338-789c6766-7a97-47e3-ab94-d59a99f9bd5b).
I created a role:

```yaml
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: postman-role
rules:
- apiGroups: ["*", ""] # "" indicates the core API group
  resources: ["pods", "services", "deployments", "data"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list", "create", "update", "delete"]
```

I create the role:

```bash
kubectl apply -f postman-role.yaml
```

I bind the role:

```bash
kubectl create rolebinding postman:postman-role --clusterrole postman-role --serviceaccount opa:postman
```

I created a token for the service

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: postman-long-lived-secret
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/service-account.name: postman
type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
```

Attached the secret, converted it to base64 and export it into a `cert` file

```bash
kubectl apply -f postman-service-account-token.yaml
TOKEN=$(kubectl get secret postman-long-lived-secret -o json | jq -Mr '.data.token' | base64 -d)
kubectl get secret postman-long-lived-secret -o json | jq -Mr '.data["ca.crt"]' | base64 -d > ca.crt
```

I see that the service account is attached to the token:

```bash
kubectl describe serviceaccount postman
Name:                postman
Namespace:           opa
Labels:              <none>
Annotations:         <none>
Image pull secrets:  <none>
Mountable secrets:   <none>
Tokens:              postman-long-lived-secret
Events:              <none>
```

I set the token in an `env` variable and copy the `AWS` `EKS` public endpoint into a variable just like in the article. I set the `ca.cert` in the settings client
certificates.
The token is present in the request headers.
I try to call the `opa` API to `v1/data` and get the error:

```json
{
    "kind": "Status",
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "metadata": {},
    "status": "Failure",
    "message": "forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:opa:postman\" cannot get path \"/v1/data\"",
    "reason": "Forbidden",
    "details": {},
    "code": 403
}
```

Maybe the relative path is wrong? I also tried `opa/v1/data` with the same result.
I struggle with it all day. Any direction will be highly appreciated.
Please tell me if any further information is required.